# Why was this custom flag declined when there is no VLQ option?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, custom-flags

I saw [a question with quite obvious problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42151126/6214222) ([deleted; screenshot for <10kers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZzdX.png)), however, because it got retagged from [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) to a completely irrelevant tag ([discussion-board](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discussion-board)) it most likely won't be seen by anyone else (only two people follow that tag) and will therefore not be closed at all.

I voted to close it but as said that is probably not going to change anything, so I thought a little bit about whether I should edit and re-tag it - with the proper tags of course - so that more people can see and close it. But I'm also not really in favour of editing very low quality questions that should really just be deleted altogether, so I went ahead to flag it as VLQ as well.

However, to my surprise it seems like after you vote to close a question there is no option for you to flag it as VLQ. The options reduce to this:

[image: spam, rude or abusive, custom]

Obviously the questions is neither spam, nor abusive or rude, which should mean that any other flagging reason has to be done via a custom flag. My custom flag explanation was this:

> This question is unclear, opinion based, too broad and lacks basic
>   spelling and any code to be able to check for mistakes. It's also
>   asking for opinions on legal advice about patenting an algorithm. Most
>   importantly it is tagged with a completely irrelevant tag which means
>   it's probably not going to be seen by anyone.

It got declined shortly after with this explanation:

> declined - Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and
>   resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of
>   standard flags: see [What is Flagging](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)?

When the custom flag description says: *"A problem not listed above that requires action by a moderator."* and the problem is not listed above but still requires action by a moderator, what am I supposed to do? Was my flag description not specific enough? Or should I not have flagged it at all?

Comment: Voting to close dumps it into a queue of questions pending closure, so if you saw it and voted on it, others will, too. And then there's the nuclear option: bringing it to Meta.

Comment: @CodyGray Well, yes that is sort of true. There have still been quite a few times when I've voted to close an obviously bad question without it ever even receiving a second close vote (or any downvotes). But this question should really be deleted instead of just closed which is my main point here (and also the fact that the moderator told me to use standard flags even though the given options don't fit).

Comment: It can be deleted by 10k+ rep users 2 days after it is closed or 20k+ rep users immediately after it is closed if it has a score of -3

Comment: It is kinda ridiculous that this flag is getting rejected.  We might have a problem with a moderator that is aiming to have the top ranking in the "number of flags handled" list instead of seriously looking at them.  We'll get rid of the junk.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Or should I not have flagged it at all?

That is correct. Voting to close was enough.

And anyway, if you really don't like the time it takes for more close votes to come in, a VLQ flag probably isn't the best choice. VLQ flags don't magically make it more visible to close voters—they drop the question into a review queue where most (16 of today's top 20) reviewers don't have 3K reputation. If they flag to close, that just puts it in another queue that it was *already in* to be seen by 3Kers.

Meta is the ["nuclear option"](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/204311/335772) as Cody Gray pointed out, but posting on Meta is discouraged unless you actually have something to ask about relating to the question. The best place would probably be [SOCVR chat](//chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers)—their [FAQ](http://socvr.org/faq#what-are-the-chat-room-rules) reserves their requests for questions that:

> - are really bad (low quality magnets)
> - are a bad example used to justify other crap
> - have recent activity on the question (Edits, VLQ/NAA answer)
> - don’t have enough users in that tag to close the post in time

Under my own judgement (and my judgment only), the question you brought up meets 2 out of 4 of these: obviously bad and not enough users (2 followers in the one tag, total) to close it.

Comment: We would have happily handled that one so your judgement is correct.